# Changing data type does not fix loading error

Tags: spotfire

When this dxp was originally created, the data type for one column was automatically chosen to be integer. At the time, I was ok with this as it was a reasonable type. However, it is now possible for non-integer values to appear in this column. It appears as though any non-integer value is removed from the analysis, which I suppose makes sense. When I add a transformation to change the data type of this column from integer to real, and reload the analysis, the load error persists, and the data is still missing. Is there anything that I can do to this data to be recognized?

Here is the notification that is returned:

```
Linked data table 'data': 
The column 'col1' contained at least one incorrect value: '1.5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the data source with the same data source but when previewing the data change the type to string.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the transformation didn't work?

Comment: Not sure on root cause. After several hours of fighting with same problem when I first started with spotfire I found this as the only solution.